# Using alternative maven and java version in vscode integrated terminal

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I want to set the maven version and java version in vscode **integrated terminal** to versions other than those specified in system environment variables. I am using the "Maven for Java" extension in vscode.

I don't want to change my system environment variables / restart everytime I need to switch between my
primary and secondary programming setting.

So far I have specified the `"java.configuration.runtimes"` and several other things in settings.json.
The language server recognizes this setting - all fine.
However, running  `java -version` and `mvn -version` in the integrated terminal still shows the java version of my system environment and also has troubles with maven:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
   
mvn -version
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I got the mvn command to run once with some setting combination I can't remember. It was using the new java version but still the old mvn version interestingly.

Here is my settings.json

```
{
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.7+10_hotspot",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
    "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.7+10_hotspot",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Cascadia Mono PL",
    "maven.executable.path": "C:\\maven-3.6.3\\bin\\mvn",
    "maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true,
    "maven.terminal.customEnv": [
        {
            "environmentVariable": "JAVA_HOME",
            "value": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.7+10_hotspot"
        },
        {
            "environmentVariable": "M2_HOME",
            "value": "C:\\maven-3.6.3\\"
        },
        {
            "environmentVariable": "M2",
            "value": "C:\\maven-3.6.3\\bin"
        },
    ]
}
```

As the documentation of the Maven Extension says (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven) "the value from maven.terminal.customEnv will take precedence [over the specification of java.home and useJavaHome]". Nevertheless, I tried choosing between one or the other but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The question is legitimate, but let me ask: Why not just use Java 11 and Maven 3.6.3 everywhere? Why could you possibly need a different version of Maven or Java?

Comment: It's complicated - I just can't do that. Primarily, because I need the exact development environment for my first project as it was originally intended. I cant use java 11 for that and also not the newer version of maven. In eclipse it is so easy to change the jdk environment and maven version - why not in vscode? It should be straight forward aswell. I don't want to switch to eclipse for these projects for now.

Comment: You know that you can build for any lower versions of Java with a JDK 11, i.e. you can build for Java 7 or 8 using a JDK 11. And Maven is really stable.

Comment: In general, yes. But a 100% backward compatibility is not given. Also not when the switch happens from an old Oracle jdk to openjdk. There were issues trying that out, also regarding the maven version. Also the production environment won't switch to a newer jre version soon and thats why I still require the same old environment in development aswell.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `java --version` in integrated Terminal in VS Code, it will search **JAVA_HOME** set in Environment Variables, so it's still **jdk1.8**.

But when you run the file like `helloworld.java`, the execution scripts shown in Terminal should include `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7+10_hotspot\bin\java.exe`, which means java extension tools indeed uses **jdk11** to build and compile projects.

About maven, you still need to add it to PATH, then `mvn --version` should work in Terminal:
[image]

If you set `"maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true,`, it will use **JAVA_HOME** in Environment Variables which is JDK1.8, you can specify jdk version with the following two ways:

1. When you create a maven project, you can choose jdk version manually;
2. In Maven projects' **pom.xml**, don't forget to rebuild the project:

   ```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
   ```

   More information view [Apache Maven Compiler Plugin – Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).